# Создание превью модели с помощью Tekla Open API (C#)

Tags: c#, api, preview

Может быть здесь есть кто-то, кто работал с Tekla Open API - вы моя последняя надежда!
Мне нужно проверять есть в модели превью или нет. Если его нет, то нужно создать его с помощью Tekla Open API. Может быть кто сталкивался уже с подобными и знает как это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста.) А записала макрос, думала, что он как-нибудь мне поможет (wpf.InvokeCommand ("CommandRepository", "Tools.CreatePreviewImage")), но нет, чуда не произошло.

Как сделать проверку есть ли в папке модели превью я знаю. И еще знаю о том, что при создании вручную превью оно забрасывается в папку модели и по дефолту имеет название thumbnail.png.

Comment: Приведите фрагмент кода с которым у вас проблема. Укажите проблемной место комментарием, где должно быть то, что вы хотите, но у вас не получается чтобы вам смогли помочь. Абстракно никто не сможет помочь.

Comment: Я понимаю, но код как я определяю есть ли превью или нет здесь будет не кстати. И то как я к Текле присоединяюсь тоже. А о том как делать програмно превью модели я ничего не написала потому что не знаю как и не могу найти ничего в документации по API. Там только есть как добавить превью к плагину. Писала на форум https://topengineer.ru/forum там мне ничего не ответили. А что б спросить на официальном форуме Теклы я не имею разрешения так как я использую учебную версию Теклы.

Comment: понял. что ж тогда удачи в поиске. попробуйте поискать сообщества по этому API в соц.сетях и поспрашивать там.

Comment: @NikolajSarry, cпасибо)

Comment: а можете уточнить немного в чем собственно проблема? Проверить наличие превью или создать его? Просто не совсем понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: @NikolajSarry создать програмным путем. Проверка делается легко и я ее реализовала.